# Does one get Facebook live toast/notification for a "like"?

Tags: apps, facebook, live-tiles

If someone likes a comment I wrote on a post, is the Facebook app supposed to give me a live tile/toast? Mine is still showing an old notification.

Comment: Facebook for WP is not yet stable, this is a common complain among all users. I do not know what's the origin of the problem, is it Microsoft's push service or is it from the app itself. Also, I have noticed that when the app is running, the messages and notifications icons are updated correctly once you have a new message or notification but the toast notification can take long time too show up, if it ever did. Anyway, this confirms that the problem is from the push service. We can only pray that Facebook guys man up a little and create an official app for WP with the same quality as in Andro

Answer (score 1):

The only notifications you can receive toast are those (currently in version 5.1.1.1):

- Wall post
- Feed comment
- Feed comment reply
- Photo tag
- Photo comment
- Tagged photo comment
- Photo comment reply
- Friend confirmation

You can opt in/out any of them in Settings -> Notifications in the app.